# Opencv cornerHarris error

Tags: python, opencv, fingerprint

I'm trying to detect point of interests (keypoints) in as munitiaes for fingerprint recognition:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
input = cv.imread("C:\Users\ADNAN\Desktop\FingClass.png");
input2 = cv.threshold(input,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1];
dst = cv.cornerHarris(input2,2,3,0.04);
```

But cornerHarris throw an error I didn't understand

```
cv2.error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12èstativ\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\corner.cpp:287: rror: (-215) src.type() == cv_8uc1 || src.type() == cv_32FC1 in function cv::cornerEigenValsVecs
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to include

```
input2= np.float32(input2)
```

before executing your cornerHarris.

Have a look here for more details and sample code with a sample image:
http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html

You can post your image if that still does not work.

What version of OpenCV are you using?